# Larave database model relation between itself

Tags: database, laravel, model, relationship

I have some doubts about how to design a model whith a relation bewteen itself.

In my case, I have a users table with id and coach_id. All users has an id (obviously) but users with role Runner has also coach_id referred to an user with role Coach.

First step is how to create the key on laravel table migration and then, how to add correct relation in User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that `coach_id` can be NULL:

```php
$table->unsignedInteger('coach_id')->nullable();
```

Use `unsignedBigInteger` if model id use big integers.

Then define a foreign key:

```php
$table->foreign('coach_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('set null');
```

Use `set null` instead of `cascade` because you don't want delete related users when coach is deleted.

And set up one-to-many relation in `User` model:

```php
public function coach() {
  return $this->belongsTo(self::class);
}
```

From Laravel > 7 you can use shortcut in migration:

```php
$table->foreignId('coach_id')
      ->nullable()
      ->constrained('users')
      ->onDelete('set null');
```